# Running cmd.exe through start-process but unable to pass the command to cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, start-process

I want to run a groovy script with `cmd.exe` under a different user.

I have used `Start-Process`, when the script gets executed it just opens the prompt on the screen with different user but doesn't process the `$command`.

So my question is "How to pass the command after running `cmd.exe` with PowerShell?

This is what I have so far:

```
$username = "abc"
$pwd = ConvertTo -SecureString "xyz" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username $pw

$command = "filepath/.groovy"

try {
    Start-Process 'cmd' -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $command
    Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
        throw "Error occured"
    } else {
        return 0
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error Desc:$_Error.InnerException.Message";
}
```

Comment: @Clijsters thanks for making it more readable. I will make sure, next time i post a question will post it in correct, ordered and fashioned manner.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [CMD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd#parameters), you can specify the parameter `/c` or `/k` to carry out the command.

```
Start-Process 'cmd' -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "/c $command"
```

Comment: Indeed: Just to spell out the difference: `/c` executes the given command and then _exits_, `/k` keeps the session open.

Answer (score 1):

```
Start-Process 'cmd' -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "/c $command" -WorkingDirectory $startingDirectory
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: You should add explanation.