# Pass multi variable command line to cmd.exe with PowerShell Start-Process

Tags: powershell, shell, cmd

i am trying to pass cmd.exe multi variable command line the code is running in PowerShell script as part of larger script .

the code below fails to pass the correct parameter's.

```
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
$buildCommand = 'C:\Git\Asd\build\XDA_2019.sln /m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="ASX Platform"'
Write-Host "buildCommand: $buildCommand"
Write-Host "msbuild: $msbuild"

$startProcessArgs = @('/c', $msbuild, $buildCommand)
Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList $startProcessArgs -PassThru -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Error

```
buildCommand: C:\CamtekGit\BIS\build\Falcon_2019.sln /m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Eagle Platform"
msbuild: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

tried running the command direct in cmd and it works cmd.exe
also read through and could not fix it
[Powershell: Start-Process doesn't pass arguments to cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730686/powershell-start-process-doesnt-pass-arguments-to-cmd-exe)
[Running cmd.exe through start-process but unable to pass the command to cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366956/running-cmd-exe-through-start-process-but-unable-to-pass-the-command-to-cmd-exe)

Thanks for any help

Comment: this invoking is part of testing strange compilation issue that occur only on direct msbuild .exe and not in cmd running msbuild.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current window, call them *directly*, do *not* use `Start-Process` (or the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API it is based on) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).
[GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

Direct execution not also allows you to directly capture an external program's output, it also reflects its process exit code in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) afterwards.

Therefore:

```bash
cmd /c "`"$msbuild`" $buildCommand"
```

Note the need to use *embedded* double quotes around the executable path in the command line passed to `cmd.exe`, given that it contains *spaces*.

Their effective absence is also was caused the problem in your `Start-Process` call:

- A [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) in [`Start-Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) unfortunately requires use of *embedded* double-quoting around arguments that contain spaces, e.g. `-ArgumentList '-foo', '"bar baz"'`.
- It is therefore generally better to encode all arguments in a *single string*, e.g. `-ArgumentList '-foo "bar baz"'`, because the situational need to use embedded double-quoting is then obvious.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271756/45375) for details.

In your specific case, you could make your `Start-Process` call work as follows:

```bash
$startProcessArgs = "/c `"`"$msbuild`" $buildCommand`""
```

Note: That this works - despite the lack of escaping of the *doubly* nested `"` chars. - is a testament to `cmd.exe`'s "quirks" when it comes to quoting.

---

**Taking a step back**:

- `msbuild.exe`, as any external program, can also be invoked directly from PowerShell. However, behind the scenes PowerShell transforms arguments such as `/p:Platform="ASX Platform"` to `"/p:Platform=ASX Platform"`, which `msbuild.exe` may not understand.
- There are several workarounds, with the call via `cmd /c` being the conceptually cleanest.

  - Another one is use of [`--%`, the stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#the-stop-parsing-token), but it comes with [severe limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42601912/45375):

    ```bash
    & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" C:\Git\Asd\build\XDA_2019.sln /m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug --% /p:Platform="ASX Platform"
    ```
  - Another one - limited to *Windows PowerShell* - is use to use *embedded* double quotes, which, however, relies on PowerShell's [fundamentally broken handling of embedded double quotes in external-program arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375):

    ```bash
    & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" C:\Git\Asd\build\XDA_2019.sln /m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug '/p:Platform="ASX Platform"'
    ```
- Another one - with all the disadvantages of `Start-Process` use - is to use `Start-Process` to call `msbuild.exe` *directly* (not via `cmd.exe`), which in your case would simplify your call to:

  ```bash
  Start-Process -FilePath $msbuild -ArgumentList $buildCommand -PassThru -Wait -NoNewWindow
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with

```
$msbuild = 'CALL "C:\Program Files\..."'
```